# Can I get italics in gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, vim

After a lot of searching I cannot find a way to get gnome-terminal to display italic fonts. I'm running version 3.6.2.

Specifically I would like vim to display comments in italics; I've added

```
highlight Comment cterm=italic
```

to my .vimrc but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Comment: Does this question help? It suggests using the ANSI escape sequence: `\e[3m` [Terminal that supports ANSI italic escape code?](http://superuser.com/q/204743)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Gnome terminal does support italics (at least in version 3.8.4). You can test terminal support for italics by executing `$ echo -e "\e[3mfoo\e[23m"`. If you see foo printed in italics, *foo*, then terminal supports it.

Then you have to insert the following in `.vimrc`:

```
set t_ZH=^[[3m
set t_ZR=^[[23m
```

Note that `^[` is a single character and can in vim insert mode be inserted by typing `<ctrl>-v <esc>`.

After that you have to tell vim to italicize comments. You can quickly test if it works by executing `:highlight Comment cterm=italic` in vim when file with some comments is open. Comments should get italicized right away.

I found the above instructions on reddit ([Italics in terminal vim and tmux](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/24g8r8/italics_in_terminal_vim_and_tmux/)), but I didn't have to follow all the steps listed there. My answer is the distilled version of instructions that worked for me.

Comment: Thank you!  The set commands were what I was missing in my vimrc.  Now my comments in terminal vim are italicized, just the way I like 'em.

Comment: Don't miss that Note about ^[ or you'll be confused for a long time!

Comment: gnome terminal 3.6.2 does also support italic! finally, i have italics in markdown, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No. I read `man 5 terminfo` to find out what the terminal ESCape sequences (what you send the terminal to cause the behavior) dealing with italics were called:

```
man 5 terminfo | egrep 'italics|Cap-|Code'|head -n 10| tail -n 4
               Variable                   Cap-            TCap               Description  
                String                    name            Code  
       enter_italics_mode                 sitm            ZH             Enter italic mode  
       exit_italics_mode                  ritm            ZR             End italic mode
```

Then, I used `infocmp` to dump each terminal description so I could see which terminals supported italics:

```
for i in $( find /usr/share/terminfo -type f ) ; do 
    j=${i##*/}; hdr="$( infocmp $j | head -n 1)";  
    infocmp $j | egrep -q 'sitm|ZH' 
    if [ $? = 0 ] ; then echo $hdr; fi; 
done
# Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt-unicode-256color
# Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/terminfo/o/opus3n1+
# Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/terminfo/i/iris-color
```

So, these three terminal-types (rxvt-unicode-256color, opus3n1+, iris-color) support italics. Others do not.

Since I could not find a terminal definition for "gnome-terminal" (see `ls /usr/share/terminfo/g/`, I looked for italics in all. Try `infocmp $TERM` to see what capabilities your terminal supports. Read `man tput` to see how to emit control sequences.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and apologies for not acknowledging it sooner.  I have switched to using Urxvt; it is highly customizable, and with a bit of effort I was able to make it look almost exactly like my old gnome-terminal set-up.